# Is there an external editor like the compositor in blender?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I know you can do to much stuff in the blender's compositor but it is too unfriendly for me. Do you know of program which has all these things like glare, vignette etc., all these presets ready to use with a press of a button. Photoshop doesn't have these "presets". You have to make them up for the most part.
Thx!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Natron**. Still a bit unstable though.

Other free option is the free version of **Fusion**.

For paid software try **Nuke**.